# discord.utils.escape_mentions don't work?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to use `discord.utils.escape_mentions` to get rid of mentions in `message.content`.
Long story short, I noticed that it's not working as I expect.

```
var = discord.utils.escape_mentions("test @!334765815435886592 test")
print(var)
```

Prints to me source string as output

> test @​!334765815435886592 test

However, here is the escape_mentions definition

```
return re.sub(r'@(everyone|here|[!&]?[0-9]{17,20})', '@\u200b\\1', text)
```

and if I just copy that and replace '@\u200b\1' with an empty string all works well and I am getting a nice result

> test  test

Can someone explain to me this behavior and how I can get to work this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive you're misunderstanding what escape_mentions really does. It looks like you expect it to replace @[0-9]+ with an empty string, which it does not do.

`re.sub` takes 3 arguments -- a pattern, the text to replace it with (in a sense), and the text to operate on. Take a look at this:

[image: Demonstrating what re.sub really does]

As you can see, I get `<@\u200b700796664276844612>` as my output. The interesting thing is, if I were to print it, I get this instead:

[image]

Notice how it looks the same as my original text. The reason for this is because `\u200b` is actually a [zero width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space), which when printed is invisible.

So, in reality, escape_mentions inserts a zero width space in between the `@` and the id. So in discord, instead of it being a mention, it will merely be text.

Comment: I expected that all mentions will be removed, because i read that in documentation.
"A helper function that escapes everyone, here, role, and user mentions.
Returns The text with the mentions removed."
I think it's a little bit confusing description.
Thank you for explanation. I will use my ugly definition copy :)